# Find java comments (multi and single line) using regex

Tags: java, python, regex

I found the following regex online at http://regexlib.com/

```
(\/\*(\s*|.*?)*\*\/)|(\/\/.*)
```

It seems to work well for the following matches:

```
// Compute the exam average score for the midterm exam

/**
* The HelloWorld program implements an application that
*/
```

BUT it also tends to match

```
http://regexr.com/foo.html?q=bar
```

at least starting at the `//`

I'm new to regex and a total infant, but I read that if you put a caret at the beginning it forces the match to start at the beginning of the line, however this doesn't seem to work on RegExr.

I'm using the following:

```
^(\/\*(\s*|.*?)*\*\/)|(\/\/.*)$
```

Comment: Why do you want to ignore lines like `String blub = "..."; // this blub means something`?

Comment: Where do you have that url that is matched? That is indeed a comment if pasted in a Java source. The solution is not to restrict comments to the beginning of the file, but to do proper parsing. In some rare cases it can be sufficient to only handle this special case, but it looks like your case is rather complex, with urls and stuff. Could you please clarify the requirements?

Comment: "Chop down a tree using screwdriver"

Comment: I'm open to suggestions.. but I think we can all agree that "http://regexr.com/foo.html?q=bar" is NOT a valid Java comment?

Comment: Tamas Hegedus I have a huge pile of unstructured data.  It could literally be anything.. but I need to do the best I can at getting all the java comments out of the text.

Comment: @stumped221 `((?:/\*.*?\*/)|(?:\s*//.*(?:\n)?))` This works for the most part, but for the urls such as `http://google.com` it would match `google.com` as a comment, how would you like to handle that?. I'm making the assumption that `single line comments` can come at the end of the line, if this is not expected let me know and I'll change that and it will work

Comment: Doing this reliably is not possible with a single regex.

Answer (score 0):

The regex you are looking for is one that allows the comment beginning (`//` or `/*`) to appear anywhere except in each of the regexps that result in tokens that can contain those substrings inside.  If you look at the [lexical structure of java language](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html), you'll see that the only lexical element that can contain a `//` or a `/*` inside is the string literal, so to match a comment inside a string you have to match all the string (for not having a string literal **before** your match that happens to begin a string literal --- and contain your comment inside)

So, the string *before* your comment should be composed of any valid string that don't begin a string literal (without ending) and so, it can be rounded by any number of string literals with any string that doesn't form a string literal in between.  If you consider a string literal, it should be matched by the following:

```
\"()*\"
```

and the inside of the parenthesis must be filled with something that cannot be a `\n`, a single `"`, a single `\`, and also not a unicode literal `\uxxxx` that results in a valid `"` (java forbids to use normal java characters to be encoded as unicode sequences, so this last case doesn't apply) but can be a escaped `\\` or a escaped `\"`, so this leads to

```
\"([^\\\"\n]|\\.)*\"
```

and this can be repeated any number of times optionaly, and preceded of any character not being a `"` (that should begin the last part considered):

```
([^\\"](\"([^\\\"\n]|\\.)*\")?)*
```

well, the previous part to our valid string should be matched by this string, and then comes the comment string, it can be any of two forms:

```
\/\/[^\n]*$
```

or

```
/\*([^\*]|\*[^\/])*\*\/
```

(this is, a slash, an asterisk (escaped), and any number of things that can be: either something different than a `*` or `*` followed by something not a `/`, to finally reach a `*/` sequence)

These can be grouped in an alternative group, as in:

```
(\/\/[^\n]*\n|\/\*([^\*]|\*[^\/])*\*\/)
```

finally, our expression shows:

```
^([^\\"](\"([^\\\"\n]|\\.)*\")?)*(\/\/[^\n]*|\/\*([^\*]|\*[^/])*\*\/)
```

But you should be careful that your matched comment begins not at the beginning, but in the 4th group (in the mark of the 4th left parenthesis) and the regexp should match the string from the beginning, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/gV3uM4/1)

## Note

Think you are matching not only the comment, but the text before.  This makes the result match to be composed of what is before the matching you want and the matched.  Also think that if you try this regexp with several comments in sequence, it will match only the last, as we have not covered the case of a  `/* ... /* .... */` sequence (the comment is also something that can be embedded into a comment, but considering also this case will make you hate regexps forever.  The correct way to cope with this problem is to write a `lex/flex` specification to get the java tokens and you'll only get them, but this is out of scope in this explanation.  See an probably valid example [here](https://regex101.com/r/gV3uM4/3).

Answer (score 0):

### REGEXP FOR SINGLE & MULTI-LINE COMMENTS ( JS / C / C# / JAVA / etc... )

#### Tested in VS Codium and at https://regex101.com

```
\/\*[\s\S\n]*?\*\/|\/\/.*$
```

##### This will correctly match:

```
  // single line comments

  /**
   * multi
   * line
   * comments
   * // including nested inline comments 
   * and without tripping on URL slashes (https://www.example.com)
   */

  /* single line comments written using multi-line delimiters */

  // /* single line comments written using MLDs and within a regular single line comment */
```

###### It can also be useful to prefix the regexp with two additional  `*` (one at the beginning and one after the | ) which will also select all horizontal white-spaces preceding both single and multi-line comments:

```
 *\/\*[\s\S\n]*?\*\/| *\/\/.*$

will_select_this_area_as_well_together_with // the content of a deeply nested comment
```

This can come handy when you have to do some external work on the comments (e.g. translating them). By copying the spaces too, when you'll paste the comments back in the code you can be sure they'll slide back into their original position (column-wise).

That said, in order to avoid errors and make those additional sections more clear, it should be also possible to rewrite it using `[[:space:]]*` like so:

```
[[:space:]]*\/\*[\s\S\n]*?\*\/|[[:space:]]*\/\/.*$
```

however it seems that unfortunately VS Code/Codium do not support this syntax yet, so I'm sticking with the  `*` form.

###### Note: if you are testing this on https://regex101.com/ make sure to set the `g` and `m` flags using the switch located after the "hard coded" `/` at the end of the expression.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this pattern:

```
(?ms)^[^'"\n]*?(?:(?:"(?:\\.|[^"])*"|'\\?.')[^'"\n]*?)*((?:(?://[^\n]*|/\*.*?\*/)[ \t]*)+)
```

This captures comments in group 1, but only if the comment is not inside a string. [Demo.](https://regex101.com/r/cQ8kX9/6)

---

Breakdown:

```
(?ms)                 multiline flag, makes ^ match at the start of a line
                      singleline flag makes . match newlines
^                     start of line
[^'"\n]*?             match anything but " or ' or newline
(?:                   then, any number strings:
    (?:
        "             start with a quote...
        (?:           ...followed by any number of...
            \\.       ...a backslash and the escaped character
        |             or
            [^"]      any character other than "
        )*
        "             ...and finally the closing quote
    |                 or...
        '\\?.'        a single character in single quotes, possibly escaped
    )
    [^'"\n]*?         and everything up to the next string or newline
)*
(                     finally, capture (any number of) comments:
    (?:
        (?:           either...
            //[^\n]*  a single line comment
        |             or
            /\*.*?\*/ a multiline comment
        )
        [ \t]*        and any subsequent comments if only separated by whitespace
    )+
)
```

Comment: Word of caution for the OP: the above will catch most comments, but will not work as expected when string literals contain escaped quotes, and when there are char literals like this: `char c = '"' /*"*/ ;`  (the comment `/*"*/` is not matched). These are 2 of the things that caught my eye, I'm sure there are more corner cases.

Comment: Yeah.. it doesn't match block comments :(

Comment: @BartKiers Thanks for bringing that to my attention, it should work now.

Comment: @Rawing, Sorry, just check your demo doesn't recognize a comment after a comment (in the same line) or `// bla bla */ also fails`.  See https://regex101.com/r/cQ8kX9/4